# Converting Log-Likelihood to Chi-square

Tags: maximum-likelihood, likelihood, likelihood-ratio, chi-squared-distribution

I'm using two different algorithms to get a periodogram. One outputs log-likelihood and the other outputs chi-squared test statistic, but I would like a way to convert from log-likelihood to $\chi^2$ to compare them. I've found this equation :

$-2 lnL +C =\chi^2_p $

(page 11 https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.06811.pdf This is a similar algorithm that I'm using, but it doesn't cite were it gets it from)
However, I'm not sure how to get the constant $C$ within the equation or what it depends on.

The other equation that I've found, but I'm not sure if I can use this is:

$\chi^2 \sim -2 ln(\frac{lnL(\theta_1)}{lnL(\theta_0)})$

(equation from https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780444537379500074) However, I'm not using two different models. I'm finding the maximum likelihood for each possible period.

So, how do I find C? Is there a better way to get a $\chi^2$ test statistic from a log-likelihood?

Comment: second equation is not really appropriate as it doesn't refer to Pearson chi square, which I assume is what you have. C should be 2 times null model likelihood I think. not sure though

Comment: the two equations are strictly related anyway

Comment: Provide sources for the equations you found please.

Comment: $C$ could be anything.  What has an *approximate* $\chi^2$ distribution (under certain "regularity" assumptions) is twice the *difference* between two related log likelihoods.  The additive value of $C$ disappears in the difference.  Apply the laws of logarithms to express the second equation as a difference of log likelihoods.

Comment: @whuber there's more than that. Pearson chi square is an approximation of LR statistic

Comment: @whuber If C can be anything, would it make sense to set C to be the null hypothesis ( I believe I'm using this term correctly) set it equal to the value that you would expect the log-likelihood to be? Also, thanks for responding everyone! This has been very helpful